# Sending and Receiving SMS

Tags: api, mobile, sms

I am planning to build an application where I'll be sending SMS to people and people will reply to those SMS via SMS which I need to process.

Is there any API for doing something like this? I will be building the API for India only.

Thanks.

Comment: Just check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586872/what-are-requirements-for-sending-and-receiving-sms-using-php/45587162#45587162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try [Clickatell](http://support.clickatell.com/product_guides/clickatell_gateway.php), they also support India.

Comment: Thanks. Does it also providing receiving and processing of messages?

Comment: Yes, that will be the two-way messaging, where a mobile phone can send a message back.

Comment: can you use clickatell 2-ways-messages for non premium numbers?

Comment: Clickatell is insanely costly for India... in India, people pay as low as 10 paise per SMS, and ~$600 setup charge is mind boggling

Answer (score 1):

You can try SMSLane.com , much cheaper.