# user verification using SMS (php)

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I am stuck in a situation in which when a user registers, he/she **get a confirmation SMS** on his/her mobile number, and **he/she able to confirm their application by replying to the confirmation SMS**, be repling like **YES/NO** to that confirmation sms..

Is there any SMS gateway available which provides the suitable functionality, **I mean an API which takes user input from sms reply**..

thanks in advance

Comment: I'd be surprised if any did not, but product/service recommendation questions are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin i dont think this is off-topic,, this is a good question, and can help many users... and a good topic to learn if any solution is there..

Comment: few questions are: `paid` or `free`? do you use any API currently? which?

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: @VedantTerkar i still havent found any API with this type of functionality, and yeah it can be free or paid.. I dont have any problem with purchasing one..

Comment: you need to use third party PHP api for sms sending to your users mobile
search on google for sms api provider for php

Comment: @Havelock so you say what should i do now?? should i go to GOD and ask him the answer?? what is stackoverflow for??

Comment: @SKRocks you still didnt got it.. I can easily get some sms gateway api.. but i want to take reply from the users as well. please read the full question.. :)

Comment: @NishantSolanki — The **first** hit (that wasn't wikipedia) when I searched for sms gateway with a search engine supported sending and receiving of SMS with the message, phone number and time being sent to you for the reply.

Comment: $@NishantSolanki link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388922/sending-and-receiving-sms

Comment: @SKRocks hey thanks for the link.. its looking good.. will check it out. :)

Comment: This is off-topic. Questions asking us to recommend software are looked down upon. For software recommendations, see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ArchimedesPi hehe **may be you should first check the difference between softwares and APIs**

Comment: @NishantSolanki `Computer software, or simply software, also known as computer programs, is the non-tangible component of computers.` If there's a site to *find software suggestions*, that's where this should be. But it doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: @ArchimedesPi this is a programming related question for sure,, I know there are many big reputed morons who are here not to give answers but they are here to downvote everything they just dont like, why dont you do one thing, if you dont have the answer than let someone else give it..

Comment: I have the answer - in fact, I've played around with such things. I'd recommend Twilio, but as others have stated, your use case doesn't work with Twilio in India. Have you researched it? Could you simply use a GSM dongle on a server?

Comment: Instead of allowing users to replying to the SMS message and you being charged twice... for sending SMS and for receiving one... why don't you send a secret code in sms which user have to enter into the website to confirm that its theirs? btw. Twilio is the best solution I think, it does allow receiving sms from international numbers.

Comment: @DawidCzerwinski I am already sending an email verification though my clients also wants sms verification.. :(

Comment: Wow, very high requirements :P However, if I was your customer, I would be deeply upset that I HAVE to use my SMS allowance just to register on your service. Just tell them the fact that if they want it their way, be prepared to pay 100USD a month even if no one signs up just to keep the service. Or pay 0.1USD and forcing users to re-type code from received sms :P Business people like saving money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio has the ability to receive sms messages.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Comment: I already checked it out, but as per India's TRAI regulations, in indian number we receive SMS from “XX-NNNNNN” number, so by using indian number you can't reply to that message, have a look at this doc, point number 2... https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices

Answer (score 1):

There is a definite solution available for this. Try exploring with FrontLine SMS that offers a similar functionality, though you will have to then use a 10 digit registered number to send your confirmation SMS.

How to use frontline sms:

1. Get an internet dongle from a cellular company (Idea, Airtel,etc)
2. connect dongle to PC
3. install frontline SMS
4. Frontline SMS detects dongle.
5. Frontline SMS API's available to read incoming SMS on dongle and forward to your server with POST/GET methods.

Try it out & let me know it work.

Regards, 
Mihir.
PS: i use Huawei dongle + idea connection.

Comment: so the dongle needs to be connected to the pc all the time?? and what about the response? how do I response to the SMS?? is it a feasible solution?

Comment: Yes it needs to be connected to a PC / server. Response time is extremely fast. 

So a person will get a SMS from your number.
That person can then reply to the same number. If you set it up properly, it will forward that reply to whatever API link you have setup.

I use this for a book library service that we developed an application for.

Comment: sorry brada, but i dont think that this will be a feasible solution for my clients, but good answer, will sure use it if needed in future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mVaayoo (http://www.mvaayoo.com/sms-gateway-features-benefits.html)

It supports Easy 2-Way SMS Integration with Website, ERP, CRM or any application.

They will provide the rich documentation which helps you to solve your problem.

You can go to that site and register and test it..

There are so many things in the documentation like return values by getting the return values.

Comment: it looks perfect, will have a look at it till the day end.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://routesms.com/
This is easy to use and cheap. I used it for like 3 years. They have all types of API with documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes, try [Clickatell](https://www.clickatell.com/), they also support India.

Please note that this is copied answer from another question...[original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388922/sending-and-receiving-sms)   This question is a duplicate.

[Expensive, but it is possible.](https://www.clickatell.com/pricing-and-coverage/two-way-costs/)