# What are requirements for sending and receiving sms using php?

Tags: php, mobile, sms

I want to develop a website that sends and receives messages to a huge number of mobile phones in different country. The system is developed using PHP, My question is that: What requirements(i.e configuration in php) are needed from the carrier that messages are sending and receiving via it? How many numbers are needed for this purpose if the distinction numbers are too many? Is bulk id can be used for one number to send sms for a large numbers?

Comment: Really you need to use an existing SMS gateway with an API you can hook up to. But that's OT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an account with SMS gateway providers. SMS gateway sits between your website and the mobile network's short message service center and sends/receives SMS. This is the easy way to do this becuase these gateways can proveide choices of protocals such as HTTP, SMTP, SMPP and Web services.

There will probably be cost involved with using these gateways and number (bulk) of SMS you can send depends on the kind of account you have with these gateways.

Few exampls of such gateways are `Twilio`, `Clickatell`, `bulksms` etc.